# How to enter in commands in mitmproxy?

Tags: mitmproxy

I want to filter with regex in mitmproxy but I'm not sure how to bring up a textbox to enter in command. The help menu doesn't display any help. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enter in command, you have to know what type of command you want. For example, filtering isn't actually called filter, although it is in the docs. Filtering is called limiting in mitmproxy, so press the `l` key and then you can enter in your regex.